# Sending multiple data in jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

i have this code for sending data

```
  var test={imagename:"apple.jpg",x:"13",y:"33"};

  $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
     url: "some.php",
     data: test,
     success: function(response){
    console.log(response);
    }
   });
```

but now i want to send multiple data to php.My php side code is like this

```
print $_POST['imagename'];
```

i think of an approach like this
 `var test={imagename:"apple.jpg|hen.jpg",x:"13|44",y:"33|22"};`
and on php getting `$_POST['imagename']` then split it according to `|` but i am not liking semantic approach of it.
1-Does any one know better solution?
2-Please provide both javascript,jquery and php code for answer.
3-One final question is this notation called json `var test={imagename:"apple.jpg",x:"13",y:"33"};`
Thanks

Comment: Have you thought of an array?

Comment: @pimvdb i have try using arrays but not getting logic getting errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An array is the most meaningful solution here - something like this in JavaScript:

```
var data = [
    {imagename:"apple1.jpg", x:"13", y:"33"},
    {imagename:"apple2.jpg", x:"51", y:"84"},
    {imagename:"apple3.jpg", x:"79", y:"57"}
];
```

Send as:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "some.php",
     data: {data: data},
     success: function(response){
         console.log(response);
     }
 });
```

and in PHP you can get them like:

```
<?
    print_r($_POST['data']); // dumps an array

    $filename1 = $_POST['data'][0]['filename']; // filename of item #1
?>
```

Lastly, `var test={imagename:"apple.jpg",x:"13",y:"33"};` is nothing more than some JavaScript code. It is *not* JSON. Although JSON looks like JavaScript (JS even stands for JavaScript in JSON), it is nothing more than the characters you're sending. JSON is a format for transferring data. As soon as you "unpack" it (either in JavaScript or PHP) then it's not called JSON anymore.

Comment: i would loop it, looks nicer ;)

Answer (score 3):

A little extention on @pimvdb:

```
foreach($_POST['data'] as $data) {
    $filename = $data['filename'];
    $width = $data['x'];
    $height = $data['y'];

    do_something_with_it($filename, $width, $height);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try using nested objects, like so:

```
var test={imagename:["apple.jpg","hen.jpg"],x:["13","44"],y:["33","22"]};

  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "some.php",
     data: test,
     success: function(response){
       console.log(response);
     }
  });
```

Then from the PHP side, you should be able to access it as an array, by calling:

```
  $_POST['image name'][index_num_here];

  Example:
  $_POST['image name'][0] => "apple.jpg"
```

Comment: `{"a", "b"}` does not make much sense in JavaScript.

Comment: My apologies, it really should have been ["a","b"], updating the answer to reflect this :) I guess I've been playing with JSON objects for too long

Answer (score 2):

Use arrays.
Javascript:

```
var data = {
    "images": [
          {name: "apple.jpg", x: 13, y:14},
          {name: "egg.jpg", x:14, y: 35}
    ]
};

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "some.php",
   data: data,
   success: function(response){
     console.log(response);
   }
 });
```

PHP:

```
// First.
print $_POST['images'][0]['name'] // Prints apple.jpg
// Second
print $_POST['images'][1]['name'] // Prints egg.jpg

// Looping
foreach($_POST['images'] as $image) {
    print $image['name'];
    print $image['x'];
    print $image['y'];
}
```

From your example

```
var test={imagename:"apple.jpg",x:"13",y:"33"};
```

The following part is considered as JSON (JavaScript Object Notation):

```
{imagename:"apple.jpg",x:"13",y:"33"}
```

Every JSON string is valid JavaScript as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [this](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) with much success, to send JSON data to the server. It's very easy to use:

```
var test={imagename: ["apple.jpg", "banana.png"],x:"13",y:"33"};
$.post('some.php', {data: JSON.stringify(test)}, function(respons) { ... });
```

And on the serverside you have:

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(urldecode($_POST['json']), true);
echo $data['imagename'][0];
echo $data['imagename'][1];
?>
```

Comment: jQuery takes care of the encoding and decoding of objects and array when passed as `data`.